# How to integrate JSON array into JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, request

I have this JSON array in my JS-file:

```
var markers = [{"id":"1","name":"toler","lng":"110.33929824829102","lat":"-7.779369982234709","created_at":"2014-02-21 16:19:28","updated_at":"2014-02-21 16:19:28"}];
```

However I would need to integrate this array dynamically since I have a php file which return this array from a database.

This is the link where I can receive the JSON array.

```
http://localhost:8888/public/test
```

Is there any way to integrate this array into my JS file using this url?

Thanks!

Comment: Do ajax request to the url and pass the results to your JS var

Answer (score 2):

In your PHP script, have:

```
$json_array = json_encode(array);
```

Then, to get it in your JS script:

```
var jsonArray = <?php echo $json_array ?>;
```

**EDIT**

Now that I seem to fully understand the situation, here goes my AJAX solution suggestion. Put this in your AJAX file:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:8888/public/test",
    data: { },
    success: function(response) {
        //do whatever you want here, response has your JSON array
    }
});
```

Comment: The JSON is returnd by requesting this URL. I do not have a connection between my JS and PHP file.

Comment: I see. Are you familiar with AJAX? Do you think you are able to make an AJAX request and receive that JSON as response? Actually it's all you need.

Comment: Well I know that this is possible but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my answer. I'll assume that this PHP script you mentioned does return a JSON array.

Comment: I need it to fill a variable called markers with the content of what the URL returns.

Comment: Replace my comment with var markers = response; then. If this doesn't work, the script's response is most probably not exactly a JSON array. If this is the case, you'll need to investigate via console (Right mouse button > Inspect Element > Console) what exactly that script returns in the "response" variable.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution would be to use this:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: I have tried that but I do not really know how to implement is correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a call to $.getJSON (or jQuery.getJSON ) and assign it to an array:

```
var jsonArray = null;
var url = "http://localhost:8888/public/test";
$.getJSON( url, function ( result ) {
    jsonArray = result;
});
```

This is just a simple snippet and you would put in your proper checks, declarations in the right places.

Comment: var markers = null;
      var url = "http://localhost:8888/public/test";
      $.getJSON( url, function ( result ) {
          markers = result;
      });

I still get no markers.

Comment: Is the calling code on the same system as your service hosted on /public/test.  In addition, if you access it directly in a browser do you get the JSON?